# mixed string breaking down in order and per keyword from groups

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, dictionary

I have following problem. I have hundred of the strings. Each string is composed of potentially 50 words.There is some order in how words in strings are composed. First, Level 1 words (max 6 members of L1), then child's of L1, then child's of L2 etc. Six Levels totals.

Example string composition, below, but it can be combination of level and sub-levels and length is varying - no duplicates.

string = ['**L1w1','L1w3'**,'L2w2 (of L1W1)','L2w4 (of L1W1)','L2w3 (of L1W3'), 'L3W1 of (L2w2)' ....etc]

L1W1 - Level1, Word 1 
L2W2 - Level2, Word 2

I have exact hierarchy of levels and sub-levels and members (words) of each level i.e.

Level1: L1W1, L1W2, L1W3

Level2 of L1W1: L2W1, L2W2...

There is no overlapping of words between all dictionaries/groups.

example: 
s1=['he','i','love','hates','skiing','disco','bathing']

Output (order doesn't matter):
S1: 'i love skiing'
S2: 'he hates bathing'
S3: 'he hates disco'

---dict's---
L1: i, he
L2 of i: love, know

L3 of love: sking
L3 of know: math

L2 of he: hates
L3 of hates: bathing, disco

Thank you

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: how to solve problem....ideas, solutions. Using dictionaries or matrix or natural language processing or something else..... Ideally link to half solved problem or solved problem.

How to get to transformed strings, output.

Comment: Could you rephrase that question? At least I don't fully understand what exactly it is you a) have and b) want.

Comment: of course. i have string and need to transform it properly. words within string are written in such manner that words belonging to root dict groups are first written, each root group has sub groups and each sub-group has sub groups, 6 deep. like inverted tree. there are also 6 root groups "L1".  I have to first read max first 6 pieces of string (in reality it could be <6 - it varies) and match it to word in root groups were they belong, then identify next first word and search in level 2 dictionaries and so on. final result is several transformed strings in accor. with where each word belongs.

Comment: s1=['he','i','love','hates','skiing','disco','bathing'] is a string i have. I know each word in string were it belongs, to what root group and sub group. 'he','i' - belong to two root dictionaries. 'he' to one root dict and 'i' to other. each root group i.e. 'he' has sub groups. subgroup have multiple words-no dups. final output is transformed string, several, in order to what root group and its subgroups they belong str1: 'i love skiing' str2: 'he hates bathing' str3: 'he hates disco'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible solution would be to create a tree structure from the data, then mark all nodes with the words from *s1*, and iterate over all paths with marked nodes. The paths from the root node to each leaf node are the results (*Sn*).

Here is the tree with the data from your example with marked nodes in blue and circled bold:

[image: tree with marked words]

The program:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf8
from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function


class Node(object):

    def __init__(self, word, children):
        self.word = word
        self.children = children
        self.is_marked = False

    def __iter__(self):
        yield self
        for child in self.children:
            for result in child:
                yield result

    @property
    def is_leaf(self):
        return not self.children

    def mark_nodes(self, words):
        self.is_marked = True
        word2node = dict((n.word, n) for n in self)
        for word in words:
            word2node[word].is_marked = True

    def iter_marked_paths(self, path=list()):
        if self.is_marked:
            if self.is_leaf:
                yield path
            else:
                for child in self.children:
                    for result in child.iter_marked_paths(path + [child.word]):
                        yield result

    def as_dot(self, standalone=True):
        result = ['digraph G {'] if standalone else []
        result.append(
            'n{0} [label="{1.word}"{2}];'.format(
                id(self),
                self,
                ' style=bold color=blue' if self.is_marked else ''
            )
        )
        if not self.is_leaf:
            result.extend(c.as_dot(False) for c in self.children)
            result.extend(
                'n{0} -> n{1} [{2}];'.format(
                    id(self),
                    id(child),
                    ' color=blue' if self.is_marked and child.is_marked else ''
                )
                for child in self.children
            )
        if standalone:
            result.append('}')
        return '\n'.join(result)

    @classmethod
    def from_dict(cls, data, word=''):
        return cls(word, [cls.from_dict(c, w) for w, c in data.items()])


def main():
    data = {
        'i': {'love': {'skiing': {}}, 'know': {'math': {}}},
        'he': {'hates': {'bathing': {}, 'disco': {}}},
    }
    tree = Node.from_dict(data)
    tree.mark_nodes(['he', 'i', 'love', 'hates', 'skiing', 'disco', 'bathing'])
    print(list(tree.iter_marked_paths()))
    #print(tree.as_dot())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

And the output of that program:

```
[['i', 'love', 'skiing'], ['he', 'hates', 'bathing'], ['he', 'hates', 'disco']]
```

The `as_dot()` method is just there to print source code for [Graphviz'](http://graphviz.org/) `dot` command for creating the image of the graph above. It is not part of the actual solution.

Comment: works. amazing solution. constructing data will be task for itself. I wonder about speed.... Thank you BlackJack